# How to properly reference Class field from a jQuery listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class where I need to modify some global class fields inside a jQuery `on` listener:

```
class MyClass {
  someField;

  constructor() {
    this.attachListeners();
  }

  attachListeners() {
    $("#id").on("click", function() {
      this.someField = // some data;
    }
  }
}
```

But there is no reference to `this.someField` inside the listener.

How can I properly reference it so that it will also update the global field?

I thought about passing the field to the method, and there use it, but I am not sure if it will also update `someField` globally:

```
class MyClass {
  someField;

  constructor() {
    this.attachListeners(this.someField);
  }

  attachListeners(someField) {
    $("#id").on("click", function() {
      someField = // some data;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use an arrow function instead of a regular function. Arrow functions preserve the value of "this" from the surrounding context, so you can still access the class instance inside the listener function.

```
class MyClass {
 someField;

  constructor() {
    this.attachListeners();
  }

  attachListeners() {
    $("#id").on("click", () => {
      this.someField = // some data;
    });
  }
}
```